# python - if-else in a for loop processing one column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, if-statement, lambda

I am interested to loop through column to convert into processed series.
Below is an example of two row, four columns data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
from rapidfuzz import process as process_rapid
from rapidfuzz import utils as rapid_utils

data = [['r/o ac. nephritis.  /.  nephrotic syndrome', ' ac. nephritis.  /.  nephrotic syndrome',1,'ac   nephritis      nephrotic syndrome'], [ 'sternocleidomastoid contracture','sternocleidomastoid contracture',0,"NA"]]
```

`# Create the pandas DataFrame`

```
df_diagnosis = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['diagnosis_name', 'diagnosis_name_edited','is_spell_corrected','spell_corrected_value'])
```

I want to use `spell_corrected_value` column if `is_spell_corrected`  column is more than 1. Else, use `diagnosis_name_edited`

At the moment, I have following code to directly use `diagnosis_name_edited` column. How do I make into if-else/lambda check for `is_spell_corrected` column?

```
unmapped_diag_series = (rapid_utils.default_process(d) for d in df_diagnosis['diagnosis_name_edited'].astype(str)) # characters (generator)
unmapped_processed_diagnosis = pd.Series(unmapped_diag_series) #
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, try out this fast solution using numpy.where:

```
df_diagnosis['new_column'] = np.where(df_diagnosis['is_spell_corrected'] > 1, df_diagnosis['spell_corrected_value'], df_diagnosis['diagnosis_name_edited'])
```

Comment: You got it right. Thank you.  There is a slight change if I may suggest: `np.where(df_diagnosis['is_spell_corrected'] > 0, df_diagnosis['spell_corrected_value'], df_diagnosis['diagnosis_name_edited'])`

That is I am looking to compare `is_spell_corrected` value greater than 0.